# Component PortalWrapper is missing template or render function

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, ssr

В проекте nuxt 3 добавил модуль Ant-Design-Vue
`nuxt.config.ts`:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  modules: [
    '@ant-design-vue/nuxt'
  ],
  css: ['~/assets/styles/main.scss']
})
```

Добавляю компонент `<a-dropdown>` в проект и в браузере после обновления страницы выдаёт ошибку `(индекс):1     GET http://localhost:3000/ 500 (Internal Server Error)`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в консоли терминала ошибка: `[Vue warn]: Component PortalWrapper is missing template or render function.`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код компонента:

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { UserOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons-vue'

// Types
import type { ItemType } from 'ant-design-vue'

const items: ItemType[] = reactive([
  {
    key: 'Profile',
    label: 'Настройка профиля',
    onClick: () => {
      console.log(this)
    }
  },
  {
    key: 'LogOut',
    label: 'Выйти',
    onClick: () => {
      console.log(this)
    }
  }
])

</script>

<template>
  <a-dropdown>
    <a-button :shape="'circle'" :type="'primary'" :size="'large'" :icon="h(UserOutlined)"></a-button>
    <template #overlay>
      <h1>menu</h1>
      <a-menu
        :items="items"
      />
    </template>
  </a-dropdown>
</template>
```

**Может кто подсказать почему так происходит и как это исправить ? при этом остальные  компоненты ant-design-vue работают корректно**

Comment: Вам лучше бы issue написать разработчику в github. Модуль совсем свежий, скорее всего где-то косяк в коде у него.